# Check if Thunderbird/Icedove has unread mails from the terminal

Tags: email, notifications, thunderbird

I'd like to check whether I have unread mails, independent of the mail account, in Thunderbird/Icedove.

I went trough the parameters of Icedove, but couldn't find anything useful. The idea is to check ever *x* minutes, whether an unread mail is available or not, if so, I'll change an icon in my system bar, to notify me. I often don't notice the Icedove popups, or simply forget about them.

Comment: Thudnerbird has extensions which can show a system tray icon, with an unread email count. Firetray is one: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/thunderbird/addon/firetray/

Comment: thank you very much for the suggestions, I'd still like to script it myself - if that's possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a little shell script which make a md5sum of your several inbox files and compare it to a stored one. When the hash are different it's that you received a new mail, then make the new calculated hash replace the old one.
Run it in a cron job and use notify-send from libnotify to warn you.

```
#!/bin/bash
MAILBOXES=/your_mailbox_directory
while true
do 
    inotifywait -r -e modify $MAILBOXES && notify-send 'New mail' 'You just recieved a new mail' --icon=dialog-information
done
```

Comment: That would work, but I think that's not very efficient, considering the inboxes may be very large. Also, how would the script know, which md5sum represents the "all read" inbox or an inbox with unread mails?

Comment: Try this little script, i think it will do the trick better (As you said, the hash won't be very efficient)

    `#!/bin/bash
    MAILBOXES=/your_mailbox_directory
    while true
    do 
        inotifywait -r -e modify $MAILBOXES && notify-send 'New mail' 'You just recieved a new mail' --icon=dialog-information
    done`